# Vue 3 - Vue.delete alternative

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

What's the alternative of [`Vue.delete`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-delete) in the new Reactivity API of Vue 3?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Vue.delete` and `Vue.set` aren't needed in Vue 3.  With the new reactivity system using proxies, Vue is able to detect all changes to reactive data.

You can use JavaScript's `delete` operator:

```js
delete obj[key]
```

Here's a Vue 3 demo removing and adding object properties with vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const obj = reactive({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
    return { obj }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Object: {{ obj }}
  <hr>
  <template v-for="(item, key) in obj">
    <button @click="delete obj[key]">Delete key {{ key }}</button>
  </template>
  <button @click="obj['z'] = 'Added'">Add key z</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.21/vue.global.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My implementation is a little... custom... but I'm trying to delete a particular key/value out of an object in the vuex store. It deletes just fine, but my computeds drawing from the object aren't updating. Is vuex working differently, or did I probably screw up something else?

Comment: @RandyHall Vuex is no different.  You can even delete the key w/o an action and it would still work (but you probably should use an action).  Here's the same demo above using Vuex state, and buttons to delete a key with an action or without:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/5t4bpwks/

Comment: @Dan thanks for the explanation! My particular bug turned out to be a developer (me) issue, but this is great to know

Answer (score 2):

For arrays, using the `splice` method is the correct way to go.

```js
const numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3'];
numbers.splice(1,1); // Array ["0", "2", "3"]
```

While the `delete` operator works on arrays too, using it creates a sparse array whose length won't be updated and the element previously at the deleted index will be `undefined`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete?retiredLocale=de#deleting_array_elements

This can lead to problems when using the array later, e.g. with `v-for="number in numbers"` in a vue template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the value is an array, another option is to use `Array.prototype.filter()`.

So for example if you have something like:

```js
this.$delete(this.options, idx);
```

you can replace it with:

```js
this.options = this.options.filter((_, i) => i !== idx);
```

The result is probably the same as using `Array.prototype.splice()` because you're mutating the original array, but the syntax looks clearer.